# Environment definition gives an error

Tags: environments, align, enumerate

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% align in enumerate
\newenvironment{enumalign}[1][\textwidth]%
{\item \begin{minipage}[t]{#1} \vspace{-5.375ex} \begin{align*}}
{\end{align*} \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*\defin[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumalign}
test
\end{enumalign}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX is telling me `\begin{align*} on input line 511 ended by \end{enumalign}.` It seems to have something to do with how LaTeX interprets my code and replaces macros - but I could not get it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% align in enumerate
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{enumalign}[1][\linewidth]%
{\item\minipage[t]{#1}\vspace{-5.375ex}\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne}
{\endalign\endminipage}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*\defin[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumalign}
test
\end{enumalign}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

First of all, you have to load `amsmath` if you want to use `align*` in your document.

Moreover, the available room for the `minipage` is `\linewidth` and not `\textwidth`, so I changed it.

And now, try to see why you've got that error. Nested environments often cause errors like the one you've got. To circumvent this, you have to use command-form of the environment (begin and end).

For example, the command form of the environment `myenv` are

```
\myenv     % same as \begin{myenv}
\endmyenv  % same as \end{myenv}
```

In your case, I've substituted `\begin{minipage}` with `\minipage` and `\end{minipage}` with `\endminipage`.

About `align*` (being it the starred form), if you take a look at the definition of the `align*` environment in `amsmath.sty`, you'll see

```
\newenvironment{align*}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
```

so, I've substituted `\begin{align*}` with `\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne` and `\end{align*}` with `\endalign`.

Note that, as egreg points out in his comment, you can replace `\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne` with `\@nameuse{align*}`, which is a wrapper for `\csname align*\endcsname`.

Comment: Or just `\@nameuse{align*}` instead of `\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne`

Comment: @egreg Right. I've just taken the definition from `amsmath.sty`. I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: It works and I do see roughly where this is going. An explanation would still be very nice.